# Updating the position of element in DOM over scroll is delayed when smooth scrolling is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to add a SVG element next to the form labels with absolute position. When there is a scroll I am listening to scroll event and updating the position of the SVG.
When smooth scrolling is enabled the SVG tends to bounce over continuous scrolling.
This bouncing is observed in macOS Chrome and in FireFox when smooth scrolling is enabled.

In Linux/Windows, this can be reproduced by using [smooth scroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj) chrome extension.

I've captured the bouncing due to scroll in this recording

[bounce due to scroll](https://www.loom.com/share/d18930d0d8d24c548f3418098fe8ce1a)

```
function updateCoords(smartTip, refElement) {
    let clientRect = refElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    smartTip.top = clientRect.top;
    smartTip.left = clientRect.left;
    let element = smartTip.element;
    let position = getRightPosition(refElement);
    let top = position[0];
    let left = position[1];
    let diffX = left - smartTip.prevLeft + "px";
    let diffY = top - smartTip.prevTop + "px";
    element.style.transform = "translate(" + diffX + "," + diffY + ")";
  }

  function setOnScrollListener(element) {
    let scrollHandler = function (e) {
      let inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
      for (let i = 0; i < customElements.length; i++) {
        customElements[i].element.style.display = "inline";
        updateCoords(customElements[i], inputElements[i]);
      }
    };
    element.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler, true);
  }
```

[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pragav94/o8Lvjwx6/7/)

Comment: Not sure if there's much that can be done about this, using this convoluted approach. But this is a problem you completely wouldn't have to begin with, if you put the icons _into_ the labels, instead of having them hang around in a totally unrelated place in the DOM.

Comment: @CBroe, I am working on a third party library and I prefer not to have the icons into the labels as it would change their DOM.